How are modules loaded if you don't directly load the file
I'm wondering how exactly does Python know to use a module if the file itself was not loaded into memory am I missing something about how things are loaded in Python?
main.py
from sub import Sub

ref = Sub()

print( ref )

ref.something()

sub.py
import sys

class Sub:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.name = "Sub";

    def something( self ):
        # How exactly is sys available here if I directly imported the Sub class only?
        sys.stdout.write( "Hello, from Sub!" );

This will output as you expect;
<sub.Sub object at 0xSOME_ADDRESS_VALUE>
Hello from Sub

However it doesn't seem quite logical to me; I would expect you would need to load the sys module as an import step first and then being able to use the Sub to initialize a reference;
import sub
from sub import Sub

For the record, both ways operate as you'd expect, but the first strikes me a bit odd after thinking about it for a reason, does anyone have an explanation?
EDIT: After looking at the question for a bit maybe I'm just reading the import statement wrong, maybe it's like;
from sub import Sub, means first import sub and then import Sub() after you have loaded the file into memory and initialized it.
How can I inspect the Python bytecode, to see what exactly is going under the hood?

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html. You don't need bytecode.

from sub import Sub tells Python to read and execute the entire sub module, but to only add Sub to the local namespace, so it will execute the import sys in sub as part of that process.

It's a bit long to explain, but in a simplified way we could say that when python finds an import, it first interprets the whole file being imported (and its respective imports recursively), so in your case, it would already know what sys refers to, and then includes in the import namespace the names that have been imported.
I hope I have made myself understood.
